# how to create xml file in runtime?

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to create an XML file at run-time under my web content folder, but a **No such file or directory** error was displayed.

My code:

```
Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
        Element rootElement = document.addElement("Students");
        Element studentElement = rootElement.addElement("student").addAttribute("country", "USA");
        studentElement.addElement("id").addText("1");
        studentElement.addElement("name").addText("Peter");

        XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(new FileWriter("/WebContent/Students.xml"));
        //Note that You can format this XML document
        /*
        * FileWriter output = new FileWriter(new File("Students.xml"));
        OutputFormat format = OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint();
        XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(output,format);<- will fomat the output
        */

        //You can print this to the console and see what it looks like
        String xmlElement = document.asXML();
        System.out.println(xmlElement);
        writer.write(document);
        writer.close();
```

I don't know how to do this. Can anyone help me to fix my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer i just change the path from /WebContent/Students.xml to
WebContent/Students.xml.

just remove the / before the WebContent